# How to replace one parameter with multiple values

Tags: replacement, parameters

I am a beginner. I have a function with one parameter and I would like to replace a list of values that have names. I would like a result so that the names are not lost.

```
values = {a-> 1, b-> 2};
```

If I ignore the names, I get what I want:

```
Evaluate[x/6 /.x -> {1, 2}]
(*  {1/6, 1/3}  *)
```

But I would like to get a result like:

```
{a -> 1/6, b -> 1/3}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: sorry, formatting is lost, so readability of my question is not very good.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
values = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
asso = Association[values]
(#/6) & /@ asso // Normal
```

Comment: thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
values = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
Association[values]/6
```

> ```
> <|a -> 1/6, b -> 1/3|>
> ```

```
Normal @ %
```

> ```
> {a -> 1/6, b -> 1/3}
> ```

Also

```
values /. x_?NumericQ :> x/6

MapAt[#/6 &, values, {All, 2}]

SubsetMap[#/6&, values, {All ,2}]

ReplacePart[values, {i_,2}:> values[[i,2]]/6]

Module[{v = #}, v[[All, 2]] = v[[All, 2]]/6; v] &@values
```

all give

> ```
> {a -> 1/6, b -> 1/3}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful!